# If $p$ is prime, then $n\mid\varphi(p^n-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

How can I prove that the value of $\varphi(p^n-1)$ (where $p$ is prime and $n$ is some positive integer) is some multiple of $n$? The purpose of this is to prove that $n$ divides $\varphi(p^n-1)$.

Comment: Related: [Prove that $n^2\mid\varphi(a^n-1)$ for $n$ even](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750211)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the group of units $\Bbb Z/D\Bbb Z^\times$ where $D=p^n-1$, $p$ a prime.

What is the order of $p$?

Comment: the order is n, I have proved that.  Now I must prove that n divides ϕ(p^n-1), and I figured the best way to do so is to prove that phi(p^n-1) is a multiple of n, but I'm not exactly sure how...

Comment: @MalcolmLazarow Don't you have a theorem that says that if $f$ is the order of $g\in G$, $G$ a group, then $g^k=1\iff f\mid k$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff that follows from lagrange right?

Comment: @Omnitic Not really. From the division algorithm and the definition of order.

Comment: ah!! there we go! thanks so much!

Comment: oh... I thought i read something like that on herstein :(