# Order of $p$ in $\Bbb Z/(p^n-1)\Bbb Z^\times$ is $n$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

In an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550864/if-p-is-prime-then-n-mid-varphipn-1), it is said without proof that if $p$ is a prime and $n$ an integer, the order of $p$ in $(\Bbb Z/(p^n-1)\Bbb Z)^\times$ is $n$.

I tried to prove that, and it boils down to the equivalence $$p^n-1|p^k-1 \iff n|k$$.

While the $\Leftarrow$ part is not a problem, how can I prove the converse ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at it in the opposite way.

It is trivial to show that the order of $p$ in $(\mathbb Z/(p^n-1)\mathbb Z)^*$ is $n$. Because for $1 \leq d < n$, we have $1 < p^d < p^n-1$, in particular $p^d \neq 1 \mod{p^n-1}$.

And this shows the (a priori non-trivial) part of the equivalence $$p^n-1|p^k-1 \iff n|k$$

Comment: How could I not have seen this ! Thanks